# Python Cloud Data?

Tags: python, cloud

Is it possible with python to send data to a network and extract it so that other computers can see it as well? If so, what are some good resources to learn more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes take a look at Python APIs my friend.

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/api/list-of-python-apis

I would suggest looking into creating a Flask (`pip install flask`) application: http://flask.pocoo.org/

It's really quite simple.